# How to prevent popBackStack() from startFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Basically when I stand on my startFragment and press back, it calls this method, which is in `MainActivity`:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    navController.popBackStack()
}
```

And then my stack stands on my navigation host fragment. And when I press any button on screen it crashes, since there are no navigations declared from default navigation fragment. How to prevent `popBackStack()` to go to navigation host fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Please open your **Navigation Graph** and then check the **Pop Behavior** and **Launch Options** shown in below image, for each fragment you have.

With these option you can configure how the fragment should behave when pressed Back button.

[image]

And finally please thoroughly go through this [Article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this is not the case at this moment, as I believe. My `startFragment` is start destination. When I press back while I'm in `startFragment`, my backstack goes to my `host navigation fragment` and all I can see is `startFragment`. Now, when I press buttons while I'm in `startFragment`, it crashes, since program wants to navigate from `host navigation fragment` to somewhere else, but these paths are not declared.

Comment: Could you please post all the files and also the error log / stack trace when the App crashes. This we we can analyze better.